# How to implement xsd:decimal data type for Post request XML

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I seem to be running into some issues while uploading some data, 
for whatever reason the system is being picky and requiring me to upload 
integers for column 5(row[4] values), so far I have researched various methods
including rewriting the whole xml document with Beautiful Soup however 
it seems that the most effective way would be to use xsd:decimal type
but I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to schemas.

Can someone please assist?

I just need to know where do I put the schema in the xml string

XML string:

```
""<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<call method="importStandardData" callerName="Import Call">
<importDataOptions planOrActuals="Actuals" allowParallel="false" moveBPtr="false" replaceExisting="true" 
useMappings="true" /><version name="Actuals" isDefault="False" />
<rowData><header>Account|Level|Split Label|Projects|{}</header><rows>"""
""
```

Code:

```
for index,x in df3.iterrows():    
#print("Account,Level,Split,Project,Date")
Main="""<row>{}|{}|{}|{}|{}")</row>""".format(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4])
#print("This is Project: ",x[3])
Main_parts+=Main



xml=Start+Main_parts+End

def Upload(xml):
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,"xml")
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(soup.prettify()))
xml2 = bytes(soup.prettify(), encoding = 'utf-8')
#print(xml)
root = etree.XML(xml2)

New_xml=tree
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}

req=requests.post('https://api.System.com/api/v20',xml2,headers=headers)
return req.text
```

Comment: Is that Python code? You don't say.

Comment: yes, I am using it for the post request

Comment: Update, it doesn't seem like this is a valid approach since I cannot include the Schema in the Post request. I will continue to research different methods, including setting up the Schema within the XML document itself. If you have any useful hints please feel free to comment.

Comment: 'some issues' is nowhere near good enough. Please explain what system you are sending this data to, which programming language you are using, and quote any error message(s) accurately and in full. We cannot see your screen!

Comment: Python!, system is irrelevant, the error as stated above is on the integer submission to X sytem in an xml document, using the above code. So far I haven't been able to find a way to cast the column "total" to integers since it's in an xml document submission. I thought maybe I could submit a schema with the above get request but that doesn't seem to be an option so my only options are either to submit the schema inside the xml document or I don't know perhaps use Element tree to submit the xml for me using objects. Feel free to let me know what you think :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I have the solution, the issue was in this line of code xml2 = bytes(soup.prettify(), encoding = 'utf-8')) it actually generated Html characters for the end of each row ie '/n', so for the Total column since it was at the end of the row it somehow concatenated the Totals with the XML version of /n which means it was '100.000 #xmlversionof /n' , I ran into another issue with the use of & in the XML file but solved it by doing a str.replace('&','&amp') for all values in the Dataframe that was being used to generate the XML. Will post updated code soon.